# Best history of macro book?

Tags: macroeconomics, history-economic-thought, books, scientific-method, economic-methodology

I'd like to know if you know some book that summarize the history of macro ? I'm in Master (after undergrad) so I don't ask for beginner's book. I've begun to read "a history of macroeconomics from keynes to lucas and beyond" from Michel De Vroey but he is not very clear in his explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond Michel De Vroey's book, I know of no other book on the history of macroeconomics, as it is praised by macroeconomists. See for example this [review](https://journals.openedition.org/oeconomia/2236).

> De Vroey has a true vision of macroeconomics, he shares it with his reader and gives clear guidelines to understand the developments in the field.

Anyway, you will find below some nice references that could be useful:

- [The State of Macro](https://www.nber.org/papers/w14259.pdf), by Olivier Blanchard of MIT.
- [What do we know about Macroeconomics that Fisher and Wicksell did not?](http://economics.mit.edu/files/656) , by Olivier Blanchard of MIT.
- [The Macroeconomist as Scientist and Engineer](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/mankiw/files/macroeconomist_as_scientist.pdf), by Gregory Mankiw of Harvard.
- Slideshares on [a Brief History of Macroeconomics](https://prezi.com/zr8i4rxdaq0u/a-brief-history-of-macroeconomics/) by Markus Brunnermeier and Delwin Olivan of Princeton.